# Circular neighborhood operations

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, matlab, pattern-recognition

Assume that I have a grayscale image. Consider a circular neighborhood window around each pixel. I need to calculate the variance of the pixel values in those circular neighborhoods.

How can I efficiently implement circular neighborhood operations in MatLab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use matlab's `stdfilt` to get the local variance.

```
 J = stdfilt(I, NHOOD)
```

calculates the local standard deviation of the input image I, where you specify the neighborhood in NHOOD. NHOOD is a multidimensional array of zeros and ones where the nonzero elements specify the neighbors. NHOOD's size must be odd in each dimension. So for **circular neighborhood** you can use the disk filter with a >0 condition that makes it binary:

```
 NHOOD = fspecial('disk',radius)>0;
```

where radius is some number, the bigger the number the more "circular" the filter, play with it and see...

Last, the local variance is just `J.^2`

Comment: Hi is there any way to get color histogram of a circular neighbourhood around a pixel?

Comment: of course there is, it is worth a new question though because it'll have a much different answer...

Comment: please answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233949/circular-neighborhood-operations-matlab-color-histogram