# Circular neighborhood operations: matlab color histogram

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

Assume that I have a grayscale image. Consider a circular neighborhood window around each pixel. I need to get color histogram of circular neighbourhoods around each pixel.

How can I efficiently implement circular neighborhood operations for this problem in MatLab?

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you show us some simple pseudocode further explaining what you want as your question isn't clear. Do you want to create a histogram for each pixel/neighborhood? Do you want a single histogram created from the average of each neighborhood?

Comment: Do you want a histogram for the neighborhood each pixel or a histogram over the neighborhoods of all pixels?

Comment: I need to create histogram of a circular neighborhood.

Comment: Consider circles of radius R around each pixel. I need to create histograms of the pixel values inside each circle.

Comment: so if if you have an image that is NxM pixel, the result of your algorithm would be a NxM histograms or 1 histogram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to give you everything, but I think this should help you out a lot.

Well you can make a circle of ones doing something like

```
h = fspecial('disk',rad);
h = h>0;
```

Then you can put that anywhere in a larger matrix doing something like

```
h2 = zeros(N,M);
h2(c_offset-rad:c_offset+rad,r_offset-rad:r_offset+rad) = h;
```

Now you have a matrix the same size (col/row size) as your image. You can use this as a reference table for getting data from a matrix, much in the same way you can return only the values above 0.5 by saying

```
r = rand(10);
d = r(r>0.5);
```

**EDIT:**

You'll also need to play around with the data types in some places to make MATLAB happy. For example, h2 will need to be a logical to use it as a reference table for another matrix. And hist won't work without proper types either.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think this is ok if I want to get a histogram for a particular circle. But what I actually need is: around each pixel I define a circle and trying to get a histogram form it. in that case I am wondering this approach is efficient or not.

Comment: You're going to have to for loop through all of the pixels (all of the offsets) and apply this approach iteratively. Especially if you want a bunch of different histograms. Consider that even a filter uses nested for loops.

If you want to visit N pixels, you are going to have to use an O(N) algorithm.

Comment: THank you for the reply. I think this wont be efficient. I am thinking about any matrix related/convolution based approaches..

Comment: I really can't think of any functions (or matrix operations) that do what you want. Convolution and filtering won't work in this case. They do something completely different. And I think calculating histograms is pretty slow. Recall that it's not a mathematical operation.

As an aside, you'll get a massive speed increase if your search space is a square instead of a circle.