# Small Neighborhood Centered at Pixel

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

Suppose there is a region Sigma_X that represents a small neighborhood centered at X (pixel) with radius W. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233949/circular-neighborhood-operations-matlab-color-histogram) as I attached below, but it doesn't solve my problem since it's not performed pixel neighborhood. I need small neighborhood centered at X with radius W for every pixel. For example, I have W=13, so I will have small neighborhood (local window) with size 13x13.

```
NHOOD = fspecial('disk',radius)>0;
h2 = zeros(N,M);
h2(c_offset-rad:c_offset+rad,r_offset-rad:r_offset+rad) = h;
```

Please help me.

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Is this about filtering the image (sliding window?)

Comment: I just want to save the neighborhood in matrix so that will be used in a formula later

Comment: `image(h2>0)` is all the pixels selected by the mask.

Comment: Is that will output the neighborhood for each pixel? Because after I have the neighborhood, I want to separate it into 2 regions based on the intensity.

Comment: That's the neighborhood for one pixel. You then need to iterate over all pixels by adjusting `c_offset` and `r_offset` appropriately. Those are the variables that determine the position of the disk over the image.

Comment: Hmmm will that the pixel will be the center? Iam confused. Could you please answer it below in "Add an answer" so I can understand it well?

Comment: I can't understand how's image(h2>0) going to work as neigborhood of one pixel.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to clarify the notations? What is `h`? Also, what exactly is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: h = NHOOD>0. I want to compute neighborhood centered at x (one pixel) with radius w.

Comment: The paper just mentioned sigma_x is small region (neighborhood) centered at x with radius w.